# How to batch-rename files using bash script?

Tags: bash, rename

I have multiple files in one directory with below format, so I want to rename all like below:

From

```
27_07_2017file1vc001vpxd-1605.log
27_07_2017case2vc001vpxd-9169.log
27_07_2017server3vc001vpxd-4640.log
27_07_2017file24vc001vpxd-9170.log
27_07_2017files5vc001vpxd-4641.log
```

To

```
file1vc001vpxd-1605_27_07_2017_1.log
case2vc001vpxd-9169_27_07_2017_1.log
server3vc001vpxd-4640_27_07_2017_1.log
file24vc001vpxd-9170_27_07_2017_1.log
files5vc001vp-4641_27_07_2017_1.log
```

Need to change on format of files from `datefilename.log` to format `filename.date_1.log`

Please not to suggest using `rename` command, since it doesn't work in my linux server.

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried `mv 07-2017filename.log filename_31-07-2017_1.log`? If you post your script code and a error message we might be able to help you more.

Comment: why doesn't `rename` work? is it not installed?  do you only have the primitive `rename` from util-linux?    In either case, install the perl `File::Rename` version of `rename`.   It can easily do exactly what you want and is the best tool for this job.  It's in the `rename` package on debian-like distros, and many others also have their own package of `File::Rename`

Comment: @cas is right. `rename` is the right tool for the job. There is no such thing as "It doesn't work". Maybe you need some help installing it, but that's a different issue.

Comment: You’ve got ***three** different* versions of the renaming pattern. Your examples are ``_<date>_1``, you say `.<date>_1` in the text of the question, and you say `_<date>.1` in a comment.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a bash script for that (**revised for general case** based on OP's revised question):

```
for file in ./*.log; do 
    echo mv "$file" "${file:12:$((${#file}-16))}_${file:2:10}_1.log";
done
```

Above the `${file:X:Y}` is bash substring expansion syntax `${variable:offset:length}` and get *length* of characters start from *offset* from its `variable` (or parameter) and rename with `mv` command. Just remove the `echo` once you ensure the result is expected as you want.

The result of above is as following:

```
mv ./27_07_2017case5.log case5_27_07_2017_1.log
mv ./27_07_2017file1vc001vpxd-1605.log file1vc001vpxd-1605_27_07_2017_1.log
mv ./27_07_2017file2vc001vpxd-9169.log file2vc001vpxd-9169_27_07_2017_1.log
mv ./27_07_2017file3vc001vpxd-4640.log file3vc001vpxd-4640_27_07_2017_1.log
mv ./27_07_2017file4vc001vpxd-9170.log file4vc001vpxd-9170_27_07_2017_1.log
mv ./27_07_2017file5.log file5_27_07_2017_1.log
mv ./27_07_2017file5vc001vpxd-4641.log file5vc001vpxd-4641_27_07_2017_1.log
mv ./27_07_2017number-blahblahblah5.log number-blahblahblah5_27_07_2017_1.log
mv ./27_07_2017number-blahblahblah5AAABBC.log number-blahblahblah5AAABBC_27_07_2017_1.log
mv ./27_07_2017number5.log number5_27_07_2017_1.log
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case there are two components:
*filename* and *date*

**list all log files with recursive search**

```
find "$(pwd)" -type f -iname "*.log" > loglist
```

**list all log files without recurse to sub-directories**

```
find "$(pwd)" -maxdepth 0 -type f -iname "*.log" > loglist
```

**Now, using `while` loop you can move files to the desired format**

```
while read f;
do
    # filename only and not complete path
    fname_only=$(basename "$f");
    
    # directory name only without filename
    dirname_only=$(dirname "$f");
    
    # use cut command to extract first 10 characters as date from filename
    date_only=$(echo "$fname_only" | cut -c 1-10);

    # use cut command to extract 11th character onward as new filename with extension
    fname_extract=$(echo "$fname_only" | cut -c 11-);

    # filename with complete path without extension 
    fname_no_extns="${fname_extract%.*}"

    # Now, move files to their desired format recursively
    mv "$f" "${dirname_only}/${fname_no_extns}.${date_only}_1.log"

done < loglist
```

Comment: (1) Please don’t do ``find *``.  (2) ***Please** don’t* do `find … > loglist` / `read f … < logfile`.  (3) `fname_complete` is a peculiar name for a *portion* of the filename.  (4) You identify *extension* as a variable component of the filenames, but then your `mv` command assumes that the extension is `.log`.

Comment: **`find *`** may be replaced with **`find "$(pwd)" -type f`** or **`find "\`pwd\`" -type f`** (backtick, not single quote). In this case we have been specifically dealing with files containing .log extension in their filename. Hence, `mv` command has no freedom to take other extension. Also **`fname_complete`** is just a variable, so it may be substituted with any name. But, it is not understood that why you don't recommend using while loop getting input from a file containing list of all desired files!

Comment: (1) If I want to insert a nail into a piece of wood, or a wall, I could use a glass bottle, a piece of fruit (a banana seems to be a useful shape), or my bare hand.  Or I could use a hammer.  By saying «`find *` may be replaced with `find "$(pwd)"`» (or `find "$PWD"`) and not *editing* your answer, you make it sound like it’s all the same.  But the hammer is much better than the bottle or the banana, and `find .` (or, pretty much equivalently, `find "$PWD"`) is better than `find *`. … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  `find *` (a) causes the shell to scan the directory, only to provide arguments to another program whose job it is to scan directories, (b) misses files whose names begin with **``.``** (unless you have enabled `dotglob`), and (c) can cause huge problems if you have files whose names begin with **``-``**.  (1+) Why do you believe that `find *` is equivalent to `find "$(pwd)" -type f`?  `find *` will find directories!  (2) `read f` will strip leading and trailing white space, will devour backslashes, and doesn’t stand a chance against filenames that contain newline.  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  Look at the `-exec` directive in `find`.  It’s ***so*** much better to have `find` execute the desired command directly, than to have it write out filenames in an ambiguous way (filenames that contain newline) so they can then be read back in an inaccurate way. (4) OK, maybe I was nit-picking.  But the point remains, your comment says “*filename*, *date* **and *extension***” (but not directory) while your code *handles* directory, filename and date (but not extension). So it’s not a *big* problem. But (a) your code doesn’t match your comment, which is always a bad thing, … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  and (b) if, a year from now, you (or some other user) needs to use this script, but for `*.csv` or `*.txt`, you / they would need to change the hard-coded constant extension *in **two** places.*  Maintenance goes on forever.  If you can spend an extra two minutes on your code today that will save one minute next year, and another minute the year after that, and another minute the year after that, …, you will have saved time.  (3) Yes, you could replace ``fname_complete`` with any other valid variable name, … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  such as `a_rose_by_any_other_name` or `number_of_legs_of_an_octopus`, and it would work the same.  But misleading variable names will confuse anybody who tries to understand the code — including the future you — and so, like inaccurate comments, make the code harder to maintain.  If you don’t care about variable names being readable and meaningful, why not just use “I”, “II”, “Il”, “l”, “lI” and “ll”? … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … Now you know.                :-)                ⁠

Comment: Thanks for elaborating differences between `find *` and `find "\`pwd\`" -type f`. I was not aware of that. `fname_complete` may be substituted with `fname_extract`. I hope its fine now.

Comment: Oh, I just noticed something else.  `find "$(pwd)" -maxdepth 0` will find only the top-level directory; ``find "$(pwd)" -maxdepth 0 -type f`` will find nothing.  To *search* the top-level directory, you need `-maxdepth 1`.

Comment: Yes, agreed. While using "$pwd", the -max depth should be 1.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know all possible cases for filenames, so I'll show you a general approach you can adapt to your needs.

You can loop through your files with a `for` loop or use `find -exec` as you like. I think you mainly want to know how to cut your filename to pieces and set them together differently.

You can either pipe the name into a tool like `sed` and create a regular expression to identify the pieces you need:

```
newname=`echo "$oldname"|sed -E 's/([0-9-]{10})(.*).log/\2_\1_1.log/'`
```

If you place `()` around those parts you can refer to them as `\1`, `\2` and so on in the replacement string. If you need to adapt it, read the `man` page of `sed` or ask here if you don't succeed.

The other possibility is to use POSIX variable expansion:

You probably know that

```
${oldname#*201?}
```

will remove the date prefix of your filename (the `?` can match any character, so this works for years 2010 to 2019, if that's sufficient. Otherwise adapt.)

You can also combine them:

```
${oldname%${oldname#*201?}}
```

Will remove the part we extracted above, so this will give you the date only. This way you can separate the parts of the filename and paste them in a different order.

Comment: Thanks. But I have few files with different , plz treat above above filename as file1 , file2 , file3, file4, case1, case2 , number1, number2...and so on. The word "file" is not fixed in all filename

Comment: same format means - it should renamed as <filename>_<date>.1.log In other way , it should cut middle name which is after date and keep first and date middle and so on

Comment: Of course you have multiple files. But by using a loop like `for oldfile in *.log; do` you can use the given commands as `$oldfile` will carry a different filename in each iteration.

Comment: My Org won't allow to use sed cmd.
Are you asking me to try same as below-
for oldfile in *.log; do mv $oldfile  ${oldname%${oldname#*201?}}; done.

Above will give strip the date only. can you help me in separating the parts of the filename and paste them in a different order which i mentioned in my edited question.

Answer (score 0):

The obligatory zsh + zmv answer:

```
autoload -Uz zmv
zmv -n '(<1-31>_<1-12>-<1900-2999>)(*).log' '$2.${1}_1.log'
```

Remove `-n` (for dry-run) if happy.